# Vue autocomplete text field doesn't remove old value when a new value is null or empty

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, asp.net-core, vuex

I'm using Vue and have a form with a [v-autocomplete field](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/autocompletes#autocomplete)

When I fetch a new object to fill the form, if the current field has some value ex. 'San Francisco' and the new value of that same field is blank/null then the field doesn't get updated with a blank field, it remains 'San Francisco'

I'm trying to figure out if it's some property on the [v-autocomplete field](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/autocompletes#autocomplete)

```html
<template>
  <v-container>
  <v-layout column style="position: fixed; top: 80px; right: 10px;">
            <v-btn @click="clickCloseBtn" fab small :disabled="!canClose"><v-icon>close</v-icon></v-btn>
            <v-btn @click="toggleEdit" fab small><v-icon v-if="!editMode">edit</v-icon><v-icon v-else="editMode" color="red">edit</v-icon></v-btn>
            <v-btn @click="goToFirst" fab small :disabled="!hasPrev"><v-icon>first_page</v-icon></v-btn>
            <v-btn @click="goToPrev" fab small :disabled="!hasPrev"><v-icon>chevron_left</v-icon></v-btn>
            <v-btn @click="goToNext" fab small :disabled="!hasNext"><v-icon>chevron_right</v-icon></v-btn>
            <v-btn @click="goToLast" fab small :disabled="!hasNext"><v-icon>last_page</v-icon></v-btn>
        </v-layout>
  <v-layout row wrap>
            <v-flex md2 px-1>
                <div class="subheader hover" @click="toggleExpandJobsite"><v-icon v-show="!expandJobsite" color="black">expand_more</v-icon><v-icon v-show="expandJobsite" color="black">expand_less</v-icon> Jobsite</div>
            </v-flex>
            <v-flex md3 px-1>
                <v-autocomplete v-model="jobsiteId"
                                :items="jobsiteCodeOptions"
                                :search-input.sync="jobsiteCodeSearch"
                                label="Jobsite Code"
                                @input="inputJobsiteCode"
                                clearable
                                hide-no-data
                                dense
                                :disabled="!editMode">
                </v-autocomplete>
            </v-flex>
            <v-flex md4 px-1>
                <v-text-field v-model="jobsiteName" label="Jobsite Name" disabled></v-text-field>
            </v-flex>
            <v-flex md3 px-1>
                <v-autocomplete v-model="locationId"
                                :items="locationNameOptions"
                                :search-input.sync="locationNameSearch"
                                label="Location Name"
                                @input="inputLocationName"
                                clearable
                                clear-icon
                                hide-no-data
                                dense
                                :disabled="!editMode || !jobsiteId">
                </v-autocomplete>
            </v-flex>
        </v-layout>
  </v-container>
</template>
```

in .vue I have

```js
export default {
  methods: {
    goToNext() {
      this.$router.push({
        path: '/Entry/Records/' + this.refList[this.refListIndex + 1].id
      })
    },
  }
}
```

and this calls the controller

```
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public IActionResult GetRecord([FromRoute] int id)
    {
       // stuff here ommitted

        var record = RecordsContext.GetRecord(_context, id);

       // other stuff ommitted

        return Ok(record);
    }
```

and get record is

```
    public static Record GetRecord(MpidDbContext context, int id)
    {
        return context.Records.SingleOrDefault(m => m.Id == id);
    }
```

I can show Record if asked!

Comment: Having a hard time understanding how you're filling out the form using returned data. Do the form controls use a `v-model` to get their data? Can you show more of the component you're using `v-autocomplete` in?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand what you want to do here.. But I wrote something that works like this: if you have something selected and go to search again, yet nothing is returned in your search, and you click off the `autocomplete` it will clear the results. https://codepen.io/oze4/pen/eorYNw?editors=1010